# Make a function which returns the original list except the argument

Tags: recursion, functional-programming, sml

I want make a function which takes a list of string and a string and returns `NONE` if there is no string in the string list, otherwise it returns `SOME` of the list of string which is the same as the original list of string except it doesn't contain the initial string (pattern):

```
fun my_function (pattern, source_list) =
  case source_list 
    of [] => NONE
    | [x] => if pattern = x then SOME [] else NONE
    | x::xs => 
      if pattern = x 
      then SOME (xs) 
      else SOME (x) :: my_function (pattern, xs) (* this is wrong, what to do here?*)


val a = my_function ("haha", ["12", "aaa", "bbb", "haha", "ccc", "ddd"]) (* should be SOME ["12", "aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd"]*)  
val a2 = my_function ("haha2", ["123", "aaa", "bbb", "haha", "ccc"]) (*should be NONE*)
val a3 = my_function ("haha3", ["haha3"]) (* should be SOME []*)
```

I'm confused by the 3rd case: `x::xs => ....` What should do there?
Note that I'd like not to use any sml library function.

Comment: What if the pattern occurs multiple times? Should they all be removed?

Comment: @tahatmat, assume it can occur only one time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't strike me as very suitable for recursion, but why not use the build-in `List.filter` function to rid the list of `pattern`? If the length of the filtered list is the same as the original list, then the pattern did not occur in the list:

```
fun my_function (pattern, source_list) = let
  val flist = List.filter (fn x => pattern <> x) source_list
  in
    if (length flist) = (length source_list) then NONE
    else SOME flist
  end
```

Note that all occurences of `pattern` will be removed by `List.filter`.

Comment: I'd like not to use any library function.

Comment: @Alex, why not if I may ask?